# How do I extract JSON data from a Django view using the JQuery - getJSON function?

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

Assuming that I have function `get_a_color` in a Django views.py:

```
   from django.utils import simplejson

    def get_a_color(request):
        colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
        data = simplejson.dumps(colors)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

How will I extract the color 'red' for example using the jQuery $.getJSON function?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? How to get the first item of an array in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're looking to do, but I put a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/Ku63j/1/) together to show how to get red out of your returned JSON array....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var colors = {colors : ['red','yellow','blue']};
    var colorjson = JSON.stringify(colors);
    alert(colorjson);

    /*
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        cache: false,
        success: function(d) { alert(d.colors[0]);},
        error: function() { alert('boo');},
        data: { json : colorjson }
    });
    */

    $.post('/echo/json/', { json: colorjson }, function(d) { alert(d.colors[0]); });

    //you would do the same thing with $.getJSON(...), if it were supported by jsFiddle....
    //$.getJSON('/echo/json/', { json: colorjson }, function(d) { alert(d.colors[0]); });

});
```